# Only The First Cookie Is Set While Setting Multiple Cookies

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, cookies

I am experiencing something frustrating with cookies. The cookies I set in php works well in some browsers. But I just tried signing into the hosted site using google chrome for android and Firefox for android and I discovered that these two browsers does not receive all the cookies set in php. I set two cookies using php but chrome and firefox only receives the first cookie and not both. Here is the format how I set the cookies:

```
setcookie('gfhfk', 'content1', time()+6000, '/');
setcookie('hfgfh', 'content2', time()+6000, '/');
```

But the two browser I mentioned above will only get the first cookie and ignore the second one. If I swap the positions of the set cookies in the php script the browsers I mentioned will only get the first one at the top. Other browsers get all the cookies. Please what could be the problem with chrome and firefox for android only receiving the first cookie and not both?

Comment: Just to make sure, you aren't sending just two different contents with the same cookie name, are you?

Comment: @Narf. The cookie names are different.

Comment: I notice the browsers you're having trouble with are both Android ... so presumably you're testing them on your phone. So... just to be sure... do you have [cookies enabled on your phone](http://androidwidgetcenter.com/android-tips/how-to-enable-cookies-in-android/)?

Comment: @Eddy. Yes cookies are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem in JS. For one cookie it worked. I see only one solution - packing the data into one cookie or using of localStorage/sessionStorage.